# Shows invalid characters while consuming using kafka console consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

While consuming from the Kafka topic using Kafka console consumer or kt(GoLang CLI tool for Kafka), I am getting invalid characters.

```
...
\u0000\ufffd?\u0006app\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u003e@\u0001
\u0000\u000cSec-39\u001aSome Actual Value Text\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd
\ufffd\u0015@\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufff
...
```

Even though Kafka connect can actually **sink the proper data to an SQL database**.

Comment: kafka console consumer deserializes in string. Obviously, if you serialize the object in another nature other than string, it will show you wierd characters

Comment: @AsierAranbarri You were right. I got "The requested embedded data format does not match the deserializer for this consumer instance" when consuming from REST Proxy

Comment: @CodeGeas :Can you please post the answer in case you have found the solution.

Comment: @Sammy Check for [answer by Robin Moffatt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517376/6188720). You can use either **Avro console consumer** or **REST Proxy API**..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you say

> Kafka connect can actually sink the proper data to an SQL database.

my assumption would be that you're using Avro serialization for the data on the topic. Kafka Connect configured correctly will take the Avro data and deserialise it.

*However*, console tools such as `kafka-console-consumer`, `kt`, `kafkacat` et al do not support Avro, and so you get a bunch of weird characters if you use them to read data from a topic that is Avro-encoded.

To read Avro data to the command line you can use `kafka-avro-console-consumer`:

```
kafka-avro-console-consumer
         --bootstrap-server kafka:29092\
         --topic test_topic_avro \
         --property schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081
```

---

Edit: *Adding a suggestion from @CodeGeas too*:

Alternatively, reading data using [REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) can be done with the following:

```
# Create a consumer for JSON data
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
         -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
         --data '{"name": "my_consumer_instance", "format": "avro", "auto.offset.reset": "earliest"}' \

# Subscribe the consumer to a topic
         http://kafka-rest-instance:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v2+json" \
         --data '{"topics":["YOUR-TOPIC-NAME"]}' \
         http://kafka-rest-instance:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/subscription

# Then consume some data from a topic using the base URL in the first response.
curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" \
         http://kafka-rest-instance:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance/records
```

Later, to delete the consumer afterwards:

```
curl -X DELETE -H "Accept: application/vnd.kafka.avro.v2+json" \
         http://kafka-rest-instance:8082/consumers/my_json_consumer/instances/my_consumer_instance
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the console consumer tools deserializes both the message key and value using `ByteArrayDeserializer` but then obviously tries to print data to the command line using the default formatter.

This tool however allows to customize the deserializers and formatter used. See the following extract from the help output:

```
--formatter <String: class>              The name of a class to use for
                                           formatting kafka messages for
                                           display. (default: kafka.tools.
                                           DefaultMessageFormatter)
--property <String: prop>                The properties to initialize the
                                           message formatter. Default
                                           properties include:
                                            print.timestamp=true|false
                                            print.key=true|false
                                            print.value=true|false
                                            key.separator=<key.separator>
                                            line.separator=<line.separator>
                                            key.deserializer=<key.deserializer>
                                            value.deserializer=<value.
                                           deserializer>
                                         Users can also pass in customized
                                           properties for their formatter; more
                                           specifically, users can pass in
                                           properties keyed with 'key.
                                           deserializer.' and 'value.
                                           deserializer.' prefixes to configure
                                           their deserializers.
--key-deserializer <String:
  deserializer for key>
--value-deserializer <String:
  deserializer for values>
```

Using these settings, you should be able to change the output to be what you want.

Comment: Console tools actually use `String(De)serializer`, or at the very least, the same logic of it (bytes to/from UTF8 strings)